# Constructing a PDA for the language of words $uv$ such that $2|u| = 3|v|$

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

Consider the language $\{ w=uv : 2|u|=3|v|, u,v \in \{a,b\}^+ \}$.

1. How to compare the lengths of the words? How to know where is the end of $u$ and the beginning of $v$?
2. What algorithm is used for comparing lengths of words in a pushdown automaton?

Comment: For the second question, the idea is to use the stack, for every symbol in $u$, push twice as many in to the stack and for every symbol in $v$,  pop 3 times as many from the stack

Comment: Like many homework assignments of this form, this could be considered a trick question. Nothing says where $u$ ends and $v$ starts. That being the case, the question becomes "is it possible to divide the string into two parts such that twice the length of the first one is three times the length of the second one?" And the answer is, only if the length of the string is divisible by five.

Comment: Your language is regular. You don't need to do any comparing at all.